# Adverbial Form of "Supplementary"

Tags: adverbs, word-formation

Does the word "supplementary" have an adverbial form?

My first instinct is the word "supplementarily," but as far as I can tell that isn't a word.

Comment: Look in Collins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Collins Dictionary:

"Supplementally" is the common adverbial form, while "supplementarily" is accepted as a rare form.